# Printing a left triangle in Java - the program works, but why?

Tags: java, nested-loops

I want to have a program that prints left triangles of a certain size, depending on user input. So if I input 5 it should print the following:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

I was able to get the program to print the right statement but I don't understand how exactly it is working. Specifically, when the first loop iterates `i=0`, and `i=0` also when the second loop iterates for the first time. But when the second loop runs, `j` is also zero because it was initialized with zero. But that would mean `0<0` for the first iteration of the second loop. Why is it that my program still runs correctly despite this? What is going on here?

My code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) { 
    printLeftTriange(0);

  }

  public static void printLeftTriange(int a) {

    for (int i=0; i<a+1 ; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j<i; j++) {
        System.out.print("*");
      }
      System.out.println("");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the first line printed out isn't just empty? If the condition of the for-loop (here `j<i`) isn't met from beginning, the loop is just skipped.

Comment: Try to find an online article on "hand execution."  This is a perfect example of when you should use it.  Note carefully the second test: `j<i` and consider carefully that the computer considers two numbers that are equal to NOT be less than each other.  For example, `zero < zero` is false.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I just noticed that! That makes so much sense. I was able to fix it. Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you stepping through your code in your debugger to get a better understanding of how it works.

Answer (score 1):

The first time the loop runs, i = 0, which means that the 2nd for loop won't run and * isn't printed. So essentially when i = 0, it just prints an empty line. However since your first for loop is a **+1**, it prints the correct number of lines.

For example, if you input 3, it'll print:

*empty line* (i = 0)

*   (i = 1)

**  (i = 2)

*** (i = 3)

To make sure no empty line is printed, simply make i start at 1.